# Loading audio doesn't work after loading image

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, dom-events

The audio file doesn't load after loading image (Javascript console doesn't display "Audio loaded"):

```
//Audio object :
var audio = new Audio("foo.mp3");

//Image :
var img = new Image();
img.src = "foo.png";

//Loading image :
img.onload = function()
{
    console.log("Image loaded");    

    //Loading audio file :
    audio.onloadeddata = function()
    {
        console.log("Audio loaded");
    };
};
```

So why this code doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the audio listener in the img.onload. This means that only if the image loads first, and then the audio finishes you will get a console.log. Solution: move the audio.onloadeddata out of the img.onload.

Edit: from your comment it's now clear that you want to load the image first. But this line:

```js
var audio = new Audio("foo.mp3");
```

already starts loading the audio..

What you want is to load it when the image loads, so do this:

```js
// Image :
var img = new Image();
img.src = "foo.png"; // starts loading image

// When image loading is done:
img.onload = function()
{
    console.log("Image loaded");    
    // Audio object :
    var audio = new Audio("foo.mp3"); // starts loading audio
    // When loading is done:
    audio.onloadeddata = function()
    {
        console.log("Audio loaded");
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. "This means that only if the image loads first, and then the audio finishes you will get a console.log" => but it's exactly what I want, image loads first, then when image is loaded, audio loads, and when audio is loaded, I will get a console.log, but that's not happen with my code in the post.